# How to check for inclusion of a value in a nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.1

In a postgres `json` field, how do I match all array items where `item["editions"]` includes `23`, using an ActiveRecord query?

```
Topic.create!(                                
  tree: [                                                                         
    {                                                                             
      "title"       => "Title 1",                                                    
      "description" => "Description",                                              
      "editions"    => [23],                                  
    }
   {                                                                             
      "title"       => "Title 2",                                                    
      "description" => "Description",                                              
      "editions"    => [12],                                  
    }                                                                                   
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some extra commas and some missing commas: i;m going to tidy the array up to the following:

```
myarray =  [                                                                         
  {                                                                             
    "title"       => "Title 1",                                                    
    "description" => "Description",                                              
    "editions"    => [23]                     
  },
 {                                                                             
    "title"       => "Title 2",                                                    
    "description" => "Description",                                              
    "editions"    => [12]                                
  }                                                                                   
]
=> [{"title"=>"Title 1", "description"=>"Description", "editions"=>[23]}, {"title"=>"Title 2", "description"=>"Description", "editions"=>[12]}]

matching = myarray.select{|hash| hash["editions"].include?(23)}
=> [{"title"=>"Title 1", "description"=>"Description", "editions"=>[23]}]
```

That's how you do it with an existing data structure which is a mix of arrays and hashes.  If you want to know how to do it via an sql query you will need to explain how you're actually storing this data in your database and include some examples.